# Bitwise Operator Shift

Tags: c++, bit-manipulation

The question is:

i1 = 254;

i2 = 201;

i4 = (i2 >> 0x02) & i1;
**i4 = 50**

i5 = (i4 || i2) << 0x02;
**i5 = 4**

i6 = i5 && i4;
**i6 = 1**

i7 = i6 >> 0x01; `
**i7 = 0**

**SOLVED**

I'm stuck on i4.

I converted i2 (201) to binary: 11001001

Shift it two spaces right: 001100100

Is shifting it two spaces to the right correct? How do you shift it by 0x02?

Then I converted i1 (254) to binary:11111110

001100100 & 11111110 = 001100100 which is 100 which is incorrect.

Comment: You only shifted one space to the right. `001100100` has 9 digits

Comment: i am terrible at maths, but I know that shifting by 1 is multiplying by 2 and that 50 times 2 is 100, maybe thats just a coincidence ;)

Answer (score 1):

If you shift i2 (201) two spaces right you don't get 001100100, you get 00110010.